# Pygame - Mixer system not initialized

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I have been working on making a Pygame for my Social Studies class and I want to add new elements to this existing game. The problem is, when I load the old game, without making any significant changes, I get an error. It seems to have a couple of warnings as well that I have looked up but most of the threads are from years ago. My error is as follows:

```
Jordans-MacBook-Air:SS-Game Jordanxxi$ python ocean_cleaner.py
2017-05-26 12:23:15.729 Python[61184:1392206] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
May 26 12:23:15  Python[61184] <Error>: The function ‘SLSFlushWindow’ is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance. Please use `SLSFlushWindowContentRegion' instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ocean_cleaner.py", line 30, in <module>
    hit = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/pop.wav")
pygame.error: mixer system not initialized
```

My code, as of now, is as follows:

```
#Import statements
import pygame, sys
import pygame.mixer
import time
from pygame.locals import *

#Pygame function to load the game and screen size
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))

#Images needed in game
background = pygame.image.load("resources/images/background.png")
slick = pygame.image.load("resources/images/slick.png")
slick_med = pygame.image.load("resources/images/slick_med.png")
slick_sml = pygame.image.load("resources/images/slick_sml.png")
diver = pygame.image.load("resources/images/diver_gun.png")
diver1 = pygame.image.load("resources/images/diver_gun1.png")
spray_right = pygame.image.load("resources/images/spray_right.png")
spray_left = pygame.image.load("resources/images/spray_left.png")
win_screen = pygame.image.load("resources/images/win_screen.png")
lose_screen = pygame.image.load("resources/images/lose_screen.png")
red_bar = pygame.image.load("resources/images/red_bar.png")
green_bar2 = pygame.image.load("resources/images/green_bar2.png")
green_bar4 = pygame.image.load("resources/images/green_bar4.png")
air_bar = pygame.image.load("resources/images/air_bar.png")
spray_bar = pygame.image.load("resources/images/spray_bar.png")

#Sounds
hit = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/pop.wav")
hit.set_volume(0.5)
wash = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/spray.wav")
wash.set_volume(0.4)
pygame.mixer.music.load('resources/audio/tune_1.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.25)

#The Variables
player = diver
spray = spray_right
spray_off_set = 0
pop=False
pop_index=0
player_x = 250
player_y = 100
background_x = 0
background_y = 0
move_x = 0
move_y = 0
keys=[False,False,False,False,False]
slick_large=[[slick,300,250],[slick,1000,650],[slick,1400,1050]]    
slick_medium =[]
slick_small = []
clean_up = 12
life = True
sprays = 30

main_loop = 1
while main_loop:

    pygame.display.set_caption('Greek Mythology Quiz')

    #How the charater moves when certain keys are clicked
    #---------------------------------------------------#
    #Move Right
    if keys[0]==True and move_x <5: 
        move_x+= 1
        player = diver1
        spray = spray_left
        spray_off_set = -200
    #Move Left
    if keys[1]==True and move_x >-1310: 
        move_x-= 1 
        player = diver
        spray = spray_right
        spray_off_set = 0
    #Move Up
    if keys[2]==True and move_y <10: 
        move_y+= 1
    #Move Down
    if keys[3]==True and move_y >-1010: 
        move_y-= 1


    #Check for collisions
    spray_rect=pygame.Rect(spray.get_rect())
    spray_rect.left=(350+spray_off_set)
    spray_rect.top=100

    player_rect=pygame.Rect(player.get_rect())
    player_rect.left= player_x
    player_rect.top= player_y    

    for i in range(len(slick_large)):
        slick_rect=pygame.Rect(slick.get_rect())
        slick_rect.left=((slick_large[i][1])+move_x)
        slick_rect.top=(slick_large[i][2]+move_y)
        if spray_rect.colliderect(slick_rect) and keys[4] == True:
            pop=True
            pop_index=i
        if player_rect.colliderect(slick_rect):
            life = False
    #When pop sound is called, volume depends on object size
    if pop==True:
        hit.play()
        slick_medium.append([slick_med,(slick_large[pop_index][1]+75),(slick_large[pop_index][2]-50)])
        slick_medium.append([slick_med,(slick_large[pop_index][1]+150),(slick_large[pop_index][2]+50)])
        slick_large.pop(pop_index)
        pop=False

    #Collision redirect physics
    for i in range(len(slick_medium)):
        slick_rect=pygame.Rect(slick_med.get_rect())
        slick_rect.left=((slick_medium[i][1])+move_x)
        slick_rect.top=(slick_medium[i][2]+move_y)
        if spray_rect.colliderect(slick_rect) and keys[4] == True:
            pop=True
            pop_index=i
        if player_rect.colliderect(slick_rect):
            life = False
    if pop==True:
        hit.play()
        slick_small.append([slick_sml,(slick_medium[pop_index][1]-75),(slick_medium[pop_index][2]-75)])
        slick_small.append([slick_sml,(slick_medium[pop_index][1]-150),(slick_medium[pop_index][2]-50)])
        slick_medium.pop(pop_index)
        pop=False

    for i in range(len(slick_small)):
        slick_rect=pygame.Rect(slick_sml.get_rect())
        slick_rect.left=((slick_small[i][1])+move_x)
        slick_rect.top=(slick_small[i][2]+move_y)
        if spray_rect.colliderect(slick_rect) and keys[4] == True:
            pop=True
            pop_index=i
        if player_rect.colliderect(slick_rect):
            life = False    
    if pop==True:
        hit.play()
        slick_small.pop(pop_index)
        clean_up -=1
        pop=False


    #Background scrolling
    screen.fill(0)

    screen.blit(background,((background_x+move_x),(background_y+move_y)))
    screen.blit(player,(player_x,player_y))

    if keys[4]==True:
        wash.play()
        screen.blit(spray,((350+spray_off_set),100))
    else:
        wash.stop()

    for i in range( len(slick_large)):    
        screen.blit(slick_large[i][0],((slick_large[i][1]+move_x),(slick_large[i][2]+move_y)))

    for i in range( len(slick_medium)):    
        screen.blit(slick_medium[i][0],((slick_medium[i][1]+move_x),(slick_medium[i][2]+move_y)))

    for i in range( len(slick_small)):    
        screen.blit(slick_small[i][0],((slick_small[i][1]+move_x),(slick_small[i][2]+move_y)))

    time_remaining = int((60-(pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000)))
    screen.blit(air_bar,(8,8))
    screen.blit(red_bar,(10,10))
    for i in range(time_remaining):
        screen.blit(green_bar2,(10+(i*2),10))


    screen.blit(spray_bar,(570,8))
    screen.blit(red_bar,(572,10))
    for i in range(sprays):
        screen.blit(green_bar4,(572+(i*4),10))


    if clean_up == 0:
        screen.blit(win_screen,(0,0))
        main_loop = 0
    if life == False or sprays == 0 or time_remaining == 0:
        screen.blit(lose_screen,(0,0))
        main_loop = 0

    pygame.display.flip()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
        #Event checkers - Check to see if certain keys are pressed
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                keys[0]=True 
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                keys[1]=True 
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                keys[2]=True 
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                keys[3]=True 
            elif event.key==K_SPACE:
                keys[4]=True
        #Check to see when certain keys are released
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                keys[0]=False 
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                keys[1]=False 
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                keys[2]=False 
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                keys[3]=False 
            elif event.key==K_SPACE:
                keys[4]=False
                sprays -= 1

end = 1
while end:
    #Exit function
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Update - I was running the game through terminal instead of Idle. I still get an error but it is a little bit different. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jordanxxi/Desktop/Game/ocean_cleaner.py", line 29, in <module>
    hit = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/pop.wav")
error: mixer system not initialized
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to do:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
```

Check the documentation for mixer (this is always a good idea to do first when you have a problem!): http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html